# Present native iOS document scanner?

Tags: ios, ios-camera, image-scanner

iOS 11 has a built in document scanner that you can launch from *Notes*. I’d like to scan documents for my app, is there a way to present the native document scanner and receive its images?

Comment: Nothing public. Possibly try poking at alternative values for `UIImagePickerController.CameraCaptureMode`

Comment: Unfortunately only `.photo` and `.video` are the available modes.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available in iOS 13+ and is provided through the [VisionKit API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit).

Present the `VNDocumentCameraViewController` view controller, registering the `VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate` delegate:

```
let documentCameraViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
documentCameraViewController.delegate = self
present(documentCameraViewController, animated: true)
```

Then receive the delegate calls once a document has been successfully captured by the user:

```
documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, 
                       didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan)
```